# Remove extract from function

Tags: php, functions

I am using this code so that users can input `[photo no="1"], [photo no="2"], [photo no="3"]` etc.. in their posts. However I heard that `extract` is an unsafe function to use. How could I modify this code to remove `extract`?

```
   function photo_shortcode($atts){
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'no' => 1,
       ), $atts));
    
       $no     = is_numeric($no) ? (int) $no : 1;
       $images = get_field('fl_gallery');
    
      if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
       $image  = $images[$no];
       return ' $image['url'] ' ;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple: Just assign the value of `shortcode_atts()` (which is an array) to a variable and use it to access the shortcode attributes in the same way you access the items in any other arrays:

```php
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'no' => 1,
), $atts );

// Use $atts['no'] to get the value of the "no" attribute.
$no = is_numeric( $atts['no'] ) ? (int) $atts['no'] : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`extract` brings variables from an array into local variables. It looks like in your case the only variable it does that with is `$no`, so you can replace extract with this code which will do the same thing:

Replace:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'no' => 1,
       ), $atts));
```

with:

```
$arr = shortcode_atts(array(
          'no' => 1,
       ), $atts);

$no = $arr['no'];
```